# Roll 2 dice adding and rolling one die, probability of being equal

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, dice

Roll two dice, add the results, call the number x. Roll one die call that number y. What is the probability that x and y are equal?

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Can you calculate the chance that two dice sum to $5$, for example?  Take each possible sum, from $2$ to $6$ in turn.  Calculate the chance the two dice sum to that, multiply by $\frac 16$ for the chance the single die shows that, and add them up.

Comment: You are correct that there are four combinations for $5$, so the chance the two dice roll $5$ is $\frac 4{36}=\frac 19$  The chance the single die rolls $5$ is $\frac 16$, so the chance they both roll $5$ is $\frac 19 \cdot \frac 16=\frac 1{54}$.  Now use the same approach to find the chance they agree on $2,3,4,6$ and add up the possibilities.